# How to lose focus on chrome extension popup window

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to implement following behavior. (1) User click the chrome extension popup icon (2) Extension popup shows up. (3) Extension popup lose focus without any user actions.

For the (1)(2) is easy, though I'm stuck on the (3).

Some options I tired:
a. Use vanilla JS for .focus() and .blur(). Though it requires binding element. Not the whole document. I don't have any control for this page user is visiting.
b. Use document.activeElement.blur() the activeElement returns  still not the whole element.

Any suggestions? If lose focus is not feasible, is there a way to force focus on current tab?
Thanks

Comment: Impossible to do

Comment: Thanks for the input. Any suggestion if "lose focus for popup" is not supported, how about "focus on window" instead of "focus on popup"?

Comment: Not possible to implement inside an extension because Chrome intentionally closes the popup when something else is focused within the browser window but there's a personal workaround: you can open devtools for the popup window, which will keep it open in this scenario.

Comment: You could take a look at the [sidebar API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/user_interface/Sidebars) which is **currently only** available on Firefox, Opera and Naver Whale browsers.
It's not a real popup window but at least it doesn't close when it loses focus.